# Cant Update Value As String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a problem updateing value when I insert string into input. My column "Location" what I want to update is a datatype: varchar() In my database. I can insert an number like "3" and it will update on the database. But when I insert a string like "SS14" It wont update on the database and I'll get an error. What I'm doing wrong?

```
   <?php
try {
    // verify request
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !=  'XMLHttpRequest') throw new Exception ('No Xrequest');


        require_once('db.php');

        $q= 'UPDATE prestashop.ps_product SET location = %s WHERE id_product = %d';

        $sql = sprintf($q,  $_REQUEST['value'], $_REQUEST['id']);

        $rs=$ib->exec($sql);
        if (PEAR::isError($rs)) throw new Exception ("DB Request: ". $rs->getMessage());

        die("1"); // exit and return 1 on success
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }    '


<td class="test" id="'.$r["product_id"].'"><font size=+2>

<b>'.$r["product_s_desc"].'</b></font></td>

        <script>
    var x;
    var h = 0; // blur fires multiple times, use h to count and fire once
    var url = 'up.php';

    $(".test").on('click', function(d) { 
        d.stopPropagation();
        var x = $(d.target); 
        x.html('<input  id="edit" style="width: 40px;" value="'+x.text()+'">'); 
        var this_id = x.context.id;

        $("#edit").on('blur', function(d) { 
            if (h < 1) {
                h = h+1;
                d.stopPropagation();

                $(d.target.parentElement).text(d.target.value);

                $.get(url,  {id: this_id, value: d.target.value})
                    .done(function(d){ if(d == undefined || d != 1) { alert('Something went wrong, check your data and results. '+d);}})
                    .fail(function(d){ alert('error');});
                $(".edit").off('blur');
            }

            return false;
        }); 
        h = 0;
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: The code is not  on the right order in the "code block", but I'm just showing the code I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an SQL statement string values must be wrapped in quotes like this

```
$q= "UPDATE prestashop.ps_product SET location = '%s' WHERE id_product = %d";
```

NOTE the single quotes around the `%s`

You can place quotes around all data values, but they are manditory around text data types.

Comment: I did It! But It still wont update in database and shows an error

Comment: Oh i found the problem, I used single qoutes instead of double! Thank you